# Setting the default select option for object data sources

Tags: angularjs

You can use `track by` to label set the default selected option with array data sources: http://plnkr.co/edit/tWr53XfvBIgtntMyZAeK?p=preview.

Yet that doesn't seem to be possible with object data sources: http://plnkr.co/edit/jji4ulB2EzushseFw8vY?p=preview

How can I set the default option with an object data source?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a string to set the default option: http://plnkr.co/edit/eXZQnVZ4DKjqd5t9luOy?p=preview

Instead of:

```
$scope.myColor = 1;
```

Use:

```
$scope.myColor = '1';
```